# react enzyme test case with mount is giving 'Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded' issue

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

All,

My application is running fine and I dont see this issue while running app in browser. I am trying to test a very simple component with enzyme 'mount'. When I do that, it simply goes in big loop and end up with this error.
In logs, something like this appears.

```
Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot set property event of #<Window> which has only a getter]......
......keep printing this error with same trace for 100 times .....
        and finally-
Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

My test case works fine with shallow mount but with that, I am limited to call any callback functions triggered by child component’s elements. I am feeling that I am writing useless test cases with that.
As I am not dealing here with states, why I see this error?

```
Versions-
 "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
 "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
 "react": "16.8.2",
```

Simple component-

```js
const GenericDropDown = ({menuOptions, style, handleChange, dropDownID}) => (
  <div style={style}>
    <Select
      value={dropDownID}
      onChange={handleChange}
      autoWidth
    >
      {menuOptions.map((menuOption, index) => {
        return (index === 0 ? <MenuItem key={index} value={0} disabled>{menuOption}</MenuItem>
          : <MenuItem key={index} value={index}>{menuOption}</MenuItem>);
      }
      )}
    </Select>
  </div>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

test case-

```js
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

describe('<GenericDropDown>', function () {
  it('should render 4 menu options', function () {
    const handleAdvancedSearchCallBack = (event) => {
    };
    const wrapper = mount(<GenericDropDown menuOptions={EXTRA_ID_TYPES} style={{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10}} handleChange={handleAdvancedSearchCallBack} dropDownID={2} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(MenuItem)).to.have.length(4);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

so, finally it turns out that JSDOM version I was using (16.0.0+) was causing this issue. all older versions of JSDOM works fine.